# Rewriting Query Parameter of 302 response using NGINX proxy_redirect

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am looking to try and use nginx to change the query parameter of an nginx response within the Location Header in a 302 response. The setup we have for internal and external websites is a little complex, but essentially I am looking to try and change the `redirect_uri` in a keycloak URL which is sent as a redirect for accessing an application.

The request looks like this:

`https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20profile&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fthe.wrong.domain%2Fredirect_uri&nonce=xxxxx&client_id=test-client`

and I want to change `the.wrong.domain` to something different so when the user authenticates, they are redirected to the right address.

At the moment the way I thought I could do it would be like this:

```
    location / {

      set $app app.example.com;
  
      proxy_pass  https://$app;
      proxy_redirect the.wrong.domain $1the.right.domain$2;

    }
```

However it appears this does not appear to include the query parameter within the Location Block as I cannot get this to change.

Has anyone attempted this before? Is this even possible?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `proxy_redirect` directive, if not a regex pattern, assumed to be a string starting from the very beginning of the `Location` header value to be rewritten, that is

```
proxy_redirect scheme://domain/...
```

I think it is hard to specify that string for your particular case, so looks like using a regex pattern is your only way. The whole directive can look like:

```
proxy_redirect ~^(.*)(\?|&)redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fthe\.wrong\.domain%2F(.*) $1$2redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fthe.right.domain%2F$3;
```

Instead of using variable for storing upstream domain name, if itis a constant string, you'd better define it as upstream, that way you will be able to use this configuration without defining a `resolver` directive defining an upstream block, this way you'll be able to eliminate unnecessary name lookup calls:

```
upstream app {
    server app.example.com;
}
server {
    ...
    location / {
        set $app app;
        proxy_pass https://$app;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response @Ivan - just tried this though and it doesnt seem to work. Can you use the args reference on responses as well as requests?

Comment: Oh, you need to rewrite the `Location` response header, not the request being passed to the app?

Comment: yeah that's the one! the app will pass the `Location` in the `302` which is what I want to change if possible

Comment: @biggbowski Updated the answer, please check this one.